# Saving a Parse.com object with a custom 'objectId'

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a Parse.com Object with a custom objectId, but the object is not saved at all.  I'm using the Javascript API. Here is an example:

```
var newsfeed = new Parse.Object("Newsfeed");
newsfeed.id = 'customid';
newsfeed.save();
```

But when looking at the list of Newsfeed object on Parse data it is not there.